# adding items onto a ListView control with multiple values

Tags: c++, listview

I want to add an item to the listview that posibly has more than one value. is that possible to create something like that?

```
item   value1
       value2...
```

both values belong to the same item, but I want them to be in separate lines.

Comment: @Satus [listview](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/listview/info)

Comment: @101010 I don't thinks that this is a question about abstract listview, it seems like `olga` has some specific listview in mind. Otherwise it would be a question about list, not listview.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774735(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Well, I am not familiar with Windows API, but you'd usually want to use tables for something like this, not lists. List is just a sequence of items. I might be wrong in this case thou. 
Or you can do it the hard way: find where gui library processes an item for displaying it and customize this process if possible.